# How to union csv datasets with different headers (names and count)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have one or more csv files that i have to merge in pyspark:

file 1:

```
c1,c2,c3
1,3,4
```

file 2:

```
c4,c5,c6
4,5,6
```

file 3

```
c1,c2
7,8
```

i need to merge the files so that the outcome will be:

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6
1,2,3,null,null,null
null,null,null,4,5,6
7,8,null,null,null,null
```

i have tried:

1. loading all the files from a folder using the load method:

   `spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true")`
2. merging the files using merge.

both used just one of the files schema

```
c1,c2,c3
1,3,4
4,5,6
7,8
```

Answer (score 1):

Read all the files - f1,f2,f3 and merge the column names. Then for each file, find the complement columns and generate new columns with lit(null). Finally, union all the dfs, by selecting the column names in order. Here is the scala solution.

```
val f1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema","true").option("header","true").load("in/f1.csv")
val f2 = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema","true").option("header","true").load("in/f2.csv")
val f3 = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema","true").option("header","true").load("in/f3.csv")

val fall = f1.columns.union(f2.columns).union(f3.columns).distinct

val f1c = fall.diff(f1.columns)
val f1a = f1c.foldLeft(f1)( (acc,r) => acc.withColumn(r,lit(null)) )

val f2c = fall.diff(f2.columns)
val f2a = f2c.foldLeft(f2)( (acc,r) => acc.withColumn(r,lit(null)) )

val f3c = fall.diff(f3.columns)
val f3a = f3c.foldLeft(f3)( (acc,r) => acc.withColumn(r,lit(null)) )

val result = f1a.select(fall.head,fall.tail:_*).union(f2a.select(fall.head,fall.tail:_*)).union(f3a.select(fall.head,fall.tail:_*))
result.printSchema
result.show(false)
```

Results:

```
root
 |-- c1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c2: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c3: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c4: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c5: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c6: integer (nullable = true)

+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|c1  |c2  |c3  |c4  |c5  |c6  |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|1   |3   |4   |null|null|null|
|null|null|null|4   |5   |6   |
|7   |8   |null|null|null|null|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: I recommend using `Dataset.unionByName` to resolve columns by name (not by position). Also, I'd change the combination of `head` and `tail: _*` with `col`.